# Gform_after_submission not returning anything?

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a Gravity Form set up, and a client would like to add a tracking code onto the thank you page. The issue is the tracking code needs to be passed the ID of the form submission.

I have tried using gform_after_submission, but cannot get it to return any values. Here is what I currently have in my functions file (this is meant to return the first field as a test):

```
add_action("gform_after_submission", "after_submission", 10, 2);
function after_submission($entry, $form){
$name = $entry["1"];
return $name;
}
```

Am I using this correctly? Also, do I need to add anything in to the actual template file (in this case footer.php) for this value to display?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`gform_after_submission` hook is supported by newer version of gravity forms have you tried `gform_post_submission` ?

```
add_action( 'gform_post_submission', 'set_post_content', 10, 2 );
function set_post_content( $entry, $form ) {
//Code goes here

}
```